# jQuery on click or selected notify button that was chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 buttons and I want to be able to detect which button was clicked or tabbed and chosen with the spacebar. I am unable to get my buttons to alert though. Will someone please help me detect which button was chosen?

```
<div id="searchoptions">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" value="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name" value="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location" value="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" value="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).on('click', '#accountNumber, #name, #location, #billingAddress,', function() {

var value = $(this).val();
alert(value);
    if (value === "accountNumber") {

        alert("accountNumber");

    } else if (value === "name"){

        alert("name");

    } else if (value === "location"){

        alert("location");

    } else if (value === "billingAddress"){

        alert("billingAddress");

    }

});
```

also tried:

```
$('input[type=button]').each(function(){

    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value === "accountNumber") {

        alert("accountNumber");

    } else if (value === "name"){

        alert("name");

    } else if (value === "location"){

        alert("location");

    } else if (value === "billingAddress"){

        alert("billingAddress");

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove trailing comma `,` at selector string. You could also use selector `#searchoptions button`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#searchoptions button', function() {

   console.log(this.value)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchoptions">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" value="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name" value="name">OWNER NAME</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location" value="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" value="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about another approach.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){ 
       alert($(this).attr('name')); 
    });
});
```

Take look at [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/dfe63qwm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```js
$(":button").click(function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
});
/* or you can use this: 
$("#searchoptions").on("click",":button",function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchoptions">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" value="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name" value="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location" value="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" value="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. I created a named handler in case you need to remove event listeners for any reason as well as make adding similar click and keydown events a bit cleaner.

I narrowed your event scope to the id='searchoptions' div to increase performance and sent both event types to the same handler function.

You could also target any other button attribute by using e.target.whateverAttribute.

```js
$('#searchoptions button').on('click', handlerFunc);
$('#searchoptions button').on('keydown', handlerFunc);

function handlerFunc(e) {
  const eType = e.originalEvent.type;

  if (eType === 'click' || e.keyCode == 13) {
    const id = e.target.id;
    alert(id);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchoptions">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" value="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name" value="name">OWNER NAME</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location" value="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default input-sm margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" value="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I removed the if statements and just used alert(id) because it provides the same output. If more generally you wanted to compare to a set of strings, you could also shorten the syntax like this:

```
var output = id == 'accountNumber' ? 'accountNumber'
    : id == 'name' ? 'name'
    : id == 'location' ? 'location'
    : id == 'billingAddress' ? 'billingAddress'
    : null;

//if output is truthy, execute alert
(output && alert(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking to do this. I figured it out.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value === "accountNumber") {

        alert("accountNumber");

    } else if (value === "name"){

        alert("name");

    } else if (value === "location"){

        alert("location");

    } else if (value === "billingAddress"){

        alert("billingAddress");

    }

});
```

Comment: The issue was trailing comma  at selector string `#billingAddress,'`